# RAVE code based Report problem with Settab and Printtab combination

Tags: delphi, rave-reports

I'm upgrading an older application (D6) in which I have a code based Rave Report (5.1.4). the program uses settab to set a box on a x/y pos on the paper, and then printtab to print the actual data inside the box.

In a simplified form it is like this (units is 1000th of an inch):

```
var t : double;
    i : integer;
for i := 1 to 5 do
begin
  t := i * 100.0;
  settab(t,pjleft,80.0,5.0,BoxLineAll,0);
  printtab(i.tostring);
end;
```

This works fine in the old system. But in the new, with Delphi 11.3 and Rave 22.0.2 (VCLD10.4), it is not working anymore. Only the first box is created and only the first value is printed. A Showmessage inside the loop, shows that all lines are executed.

NB! If I make two loops, and only execute Settap in the first loop, and Printtab in the second loop, it will work. So it is like the Printtab blocks (or resets) the result of the Settab.

Have any of you experienced something similar and if, which solution have you found ?

NB! I have the source with the Rave Report and checking the relevant procedures and functions in relation to Settab and PrintTab (in RvBase.pas), do not show any obvious reason why it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Not many replies to this... Maybe Rave Code Based Reporting is not so much used anymore.

I did report the problem to the provider and they finally came back with the expected answer, that it is necessary to first create all tabs on the same line, before printing in them.

So hard work ahead, and question closed !